# Handle spam contact requests in Skype

Tags: windows, android, skype

I receive 10-20 contact requests a day by spammers, sometimes even an unsolicited call.
This is of course annoying. Until recently, I clicked on each contact request and reported it as spam. However, the number of requests has increased so this is no longer feasible.

So far, I have not blocked contact requests in general, because once in a while people that I know contact me that way.
Real messages, birthday reminders and requests get lost in the long list of spam requests.
Any suggestions?

I mostly use Skype on Android and Windows.

What I did so far on Android was manually blocking all notifications of the Skype app. On Windows, I only run Skype when I really expect a call and completely quit it after that.

Comment: Please comment when you vote down

Answer (score 0):

I just chatted with Skype support about this spam issue. It is well known to them, in the current version (September 2016) requests can only be blocked one by one, but they promised me that development is working on a solution for a future version.

Comment: not the downvoter of your answer or question, but it seems that is the same answer they have been giving for many years now. However, never been spammed as much as you were it was usually once a month or week.